# Allow Windows 10 Domain User Local PC Admin Rights (BYOD)

Tags: domain, windows-10

A user in our company has special requirements regarding hardware and particularly software. He brings his own PC with many specialized software tools into the company, and moves his files back and forth individually between his PC and the company WiFi for editing. He is not allowed to connect his PC to the company LAN/Domain.

Is there any way we can integrate his PC into our domain in such a way that he remains local administrator on his PC, without compromising the security of our domain network?

I found something along these lines [here](https://deployhappiness.com/clever-way-manage-administrative-rights-regular-users/), but it's already a bit older.  Maybe someone has a newer view on how we could proceed to do this.

Another approach seems to be described [here](https://specopssoft.com/blog/local-admin-rights-on-specific-machine-only/). Not sure whether we'd need that script approach since it is one such user only for us.

Answer (score 1):

Joining his computer to your domain has no bearing on the local user accounts. If he has a local user account that is in the local Administrators group now he'll still have it after joining it to your domain.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand this correctly as I'm not a network expert. It would seem that our company policy does not allow the mere connection of a BYOD device to the company domain. Therefore, I am looking for a compromise solution that is as less invasive as possible while still allowing him local admin rights to his machine.

Comment: I don't understand your end goal. How exactly do you want to "integrate" his machine to your domain? If you don't join it to your domain then you have no access to it or control of it, unless he explicitly gives it  to you. You can't add domain users to his computer unless it's joined to your domain.

Comment: Would it be possible that he only has admin rights on his PC as long as he is *not* connected to our Domain? Thing is that he should be connected to the Domain for normal work, in order to have access to the intranet, the software license server etc. This however is not allowed with BYOD devices, whatever that exactly means ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Folder with less GPO or none of it inherited to the folder, and put his AD user inside, this way the user can have mostly admin rights on his device and also get the privileges to be joined to your domain.